# To compare Date and Datetime in ASP.NET mvc 3?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, date, datetime

I'm new in ASP.NET. I have date_meeting (Datetime) column in the meetings table. I want to load data from table, which are the date_meeting's date is today.
I tried any variations:

```
List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.Where(x => x.date_meeting == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy")).Date && x.langId == lang).ToList();
```

error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

I need this logic.

```
List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.Where(x => x.date_meeting.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy") == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy") && x.langId == lang).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or you can use

```
List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.Where( m.date_meeting.Day.Equals(DateTime.Now.Day) &&
                                     m.date_meeting.Month.Equals(DateTime.Now.Month) &&
                                     m.date_meeting.Year.Equals(DateTime.Now.Year) && && x.langId == lang).ToList();
```

Or try this article:  [LINQ query to compare only date part of DateTime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499987/LINQ-query-to-compare-only-date-part-of-DateTime)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499987/LINQ-query-to-compare-only-date-part-of-DateTime try this

Comment: Success : `List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.Where(x=> x.date_meeting.Value.Day==DateTime.Now.Day &&
                                     x.date_meeting.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                                     x.date_meeting.Value.Year==DateTime.Now.Year && x.langId == lang).ToList();` Thank you for link @meajaygoel

Answer (score 1):

try

```
List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.Where(x => x.date_meeting.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.langId == lang).ToList();
```

Comment: System.Nullable <System.DateTime>" does not contain a definition for "Date" and was not found an extension method "Date", receiving type "System.Nullable <System.DateTime>" as the first argument (possibly missed directive using or an assembly reference)

Comment: x.date_meeting.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

Comment: List<Meeting> meetings = db.Meetings.ToList().Where(x => x.date_meeting.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && x.langId == lang);  convert to list first and then apply where clause